# Time Machine Backup via another Mac?

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine, external-disk, firewire

Since I have broken Permissions, which can't be fixed now, because my [sudo is broken](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/316832/sudo-folder-empty-broke) too, I want to create a Time Machine Backup. Now the problem: both of my USB-Ports are broken.

After some research I found out, you can [use your Mac as a hard disk](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201462) and you can [boot a Mac from an external disk](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202796), so my idea is to connect the working Mac (Mac A) via FireWire with my broken Mac (Mac B), so I can use the hardware of Mac A with the software of Mac B and create a Time Machine Backup to an external drive.

Since I don't want to risk that Mac A breaks to, I'm asking here, what I need to do different or of this even possible.

Comment: I'm unclear what the problem you're facing with Target Disk Mode is.

Answer (score 3):

Target disk mode turns your Mac with broken USB into a fancy hard drive.

You can do anything with that data that you could with any working hard drive. You could copy files from or to it, you could change permissions, you could install an os and you could include it in a backup.

It’s just data on a hard drive shaped like a Mac.

Comment: Thanks ;) Is it a bootable harddrive or do I need to do something else to start from it?

Comment: @Nanogamer7 You need another mac if you want to run MacOS against the connected data. If you can connect to windows or linux, they could read the data too. Target Disk Mode is bootable, but the whole point is to not boot your mac and bring that data to a working OS to fix or move the data, no?